# Web3.js Error: provider not set after TestContract.at(address);

Tags: web3js

I'm new to web3.js and ethereum, and i'm trying to play with it coupled with meteor and angular 1.5.

I defined a component that creates a simple contract but i'm stuck after calling TestContract.at(address); - the error i get is "Error: provider not set" but just some lines before i send a transaction and HttpProvider is correctly recognized.

My simple component is:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';

import templateUrl from './mine-contract.ng.html';


class MineContract {
  constructor() {
    this.contractInstance = null;
    this.mining = false;
  }

  mine() {
    this.mining = true;
    var transactionObject = {
      data: TestContract.bytecode,
      gasPrice: web3.eth.gasPrice,
      gas: 5000000,
      from: web3.eth.accounts[0]
    };

    var _this = this;

    web3.eth.estimateGas(transactionObject, function(err, result){
      if(err) {
        console.log('err', err);
        _this.error = 'Something went wrong, the error is: ' + err;
        _this.mining = false;
        return;
      }

      if(!err)
        transactionObject.gas = result * 10;

      console.log('trans', transactionObject);
      web3.eth.sendTransaction(transactionObject, function(err, result){
        if(err) {
          console.log('err', err);
          _this.error = 'Something went wrong, the error is: ' + err;
          return;
        }

        if(result) {
          _this.contractInstance = TestContract.at(result);
          console.log('contractInstance', _this.contractInstance);
        }

      });
    });
  }

}

const name = 'mineContract';

export default angular.module(name, [angularMeteor])
.component(name, {
  templateUrl,
  controllerAs: name,
  controller: MineContract
});
```

In my javascript console when i log console.log('contractInstance', _this.contractInstance); i get:

```
contractInstance Contract {_eth: Eth, transactionHash: null, address: "0x0ed4a0e14bb7b1a9173271a16c12690237663eff333b2ba26e9f6dbed4695b62", abi: Array[2]}
```

But after that it starts throwing exception web3.js:5996 Error: Provider not set or invalid(…) - i presume trying to get the transactionHash

Line that throw the error is:

```
RequestManager.prototype.send = function (data) {
    if (!this.provider) {
        console.error(errors.InvalidProvider());
        return null;
    }
```

But I can't understand what i'm doing wrong.

Can anybody helps me?

Comment: Have you set the provider by using web3.setProvider(....); @bre

Comment: @The Neo Noir Developer yes in client/startup/connection.js i have `Meteor.startup(function(){
  if(!web3.currentProvider) {
    web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://192.168.1.140:8000"));
  }
  // Setup EthAccounts
  EthAccounts.init();
});` and i'm using a test net, i can send and receive ethers

Comment: Okay, check if you can access this http://192.168.1.140:8000 in your browser. and also verify 192.168.1.140 is your node (geth) running in rpc mode at 8000 port number @bre

Comment: @The Neo Noir Developer - thank you for your help Neo, yes i can - with another component i can send and receive ethers from different accounts in the testnet

Comment: having your geth is connected to network ( testnet) you would be able to do ether transfers,not necessarily it is an HttpProvider. 

Is your geth running is in --rpc mode and the address is set and the port number ;8000 ?

Can you access the address in your browser ? 

Check what is the current provider by invoking web3.currentProvider in the browser console.

check if the Meteor.startup() executes fine setting the provider.

Comment: @The Neo Noir Developer - geth command is `geth --rpc --rpcaddr 192.168.1.140 --rpcport 8000 --rpccorsdomain="*" --genesis test-genesis.json --networkid 1234901901 --unlock=0,1,2 --mine --verbosity=5 --maxpeers=0` using the browser if i go to http://192.168.1.140:8000 response is `{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32600,"message":"EOF"}}` - if i log into console web3.currentProvider from the component it logs: `HttpProvider {host: "http://192.168.1.140:8000"}`

Comment: I'm having the same problem, except I'm trying to reach http://localhost/8545 instead of 192. ...:8000, the weird part is that in the setProvider part after `if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined')` test tells me it's defined (I'm not in the 'else' part).